# Is it a good practice to test absolutely everything or it is a waste of time (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I recently learned, **Rspec + Capybara** (I'm new to testing things). And I've been testing some new models I've created. Now, I was thinking of adding the `title` column to my `Post` model. It's not a hard task, and I've done it many times before. But I realized that it's going to take me some work updating the spec files (e.g. post, post pages, user, user pages, factories, sample_data, etc.).

Is testing in this case, a waste of time? Or it is a good practice to test absolutely everything?

I also wonder if testing gems is a waste of time as well? Since they've been probably already tested by their creators (the same for testing something taken from a reliable tutorial).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the ruby community is known by its focus on testing, every case should be analyzed in context to figure out what the most cost-effective decisions are.

It is useful to think of tests as a technique to manage risk. If you don't think that displaying titles/adding them to the database is a task that is error-prone, complex to perform, or that the cost of adding those tests is higher than the risk of eventually breaking something, them it might be wise to not do it.

That said, since you said that you are new to testing, I would recommend (if you are not time-constrained, of course) to try to take the idea to the extreme of testing absolutely everything, so that you can have an idea of how much of it adds value, and how much is waste of time.

You might want to take a look at this blog post from DHH, the creator of Rails, where he talks about that: [Testing like the TSA](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3159-testing-like-the-tsa)

About testing gems, it is generally well-accepted that they shouldn't be tested by your application tests, but by their creators. Most of the time you can simply assume that they work the ways they promise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I always wondered about that. Why the ruby community focus on testing (or the Rails community)?

Comment: @alexchenco I don't have a concrete answer for that, but I think it's partly because of the fact that the language already comes with a testing framework built-in (`test/unit`), and that much of the community has its roots on the agile/XP movement.

Comment: I see. Yeah, like I never heard of the python community talk about testing.

Comment: If you're coming from a statically typed background, one reason the ruby community focuses on testing is because there is no typesystem or compiler to save you from even the simplest of mistakes. I have friends that claim that their Scala-based startup, due to their particular strategy of using the type system, has virtually no tests, but has yet to have a production bug. However, compile times are starting to hurt their velocity, so it's a mixed bag. In ruby, we trade compile times for test times.

Answer (score 1):

one of the main concepts of testing is: "It's impossible to test everything"